# Scaling Images based on device size xcode

Tags: iphone, image, swift, scale

So here is my question, I have an app where i have some PNG images that are 64 pixels X 64 pixels and when the game is loaded on i-pad simulator all of the images fit perfectly but when i change the simulator to the i-phone sizes the images don't fit on the screen size right. How do you change the size of the picture to scale right for all device sizes?

Comment: Use auto-layout in your viewcontroller. With autolayout you can create a rules to adapt your image to a different screen-size or orietation. Consider also the image resolution to improve the image for all devices

Answer (score 0):

[image]

U Can use Constraints for any ios devices like i-pad, i-phone..etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either from Xcode, with autolayout, or programmatically:

```
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
image.frame.size.width = width
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope help you

Please check the given below image.

[image]

look all indicate point.